# Remmina VNC Not Always Connecting

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, vnc

5/12/23 Update: I have returned home and done some troubleshooting of my VNC connection.  It appears to be something to do with the VNC server on the desktop computer I was trying to access.  After restarting the PC, I can connect normally via VNC.  When the PC screen is locked, as in without activity for some period of time, I can no longer connect VNC.  When trying again after unlocking the screen, I can no longer connect, Remmia on my laptop reports "VNC server closed connection." Also, after other connection attempts that have failed (like a configuration/or password mistake) the VNC will no longer connect.  In summary, it appears that any failed connection attempt "breaks" the VNC server so it will no longer accept connections.  This is fixed either by restarting the PC or by disabling and re-enabling the "sharing" feature in the settings.

In addition to the new router I have recently installed, I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.  Prior to the upgrade, connecting via VNC worked without fail.  I welcome any thoughts as to how I can make this VNC connectivity reliable again.

Original Post Below.................................................

I am having difficulties connecting to my home PCs remotely while away at work.  I have recently installed a new router, a Netware Nighthawk, and after some work, was able to connect to 2 VNC desktops from my laptop via a cellular connection via an OpenVPN connection to the router.  All computers involved are running Ubuntu 22.04, have desktop sharing enabled and have frequently used the VNC feature.  Further testing while at home showed some difficulty in establishing a VNC connection, several failures with random successes.  Now I am traveling away from home for the next 3 weeks, and can no longer make a VNC connection at all via the same cellular/vpn connection that previously worked.  I can verify the VPN is working by seeing NAS drives connected to the router.

When trying to connect, Remmina variously reports endless failures and retrying the password or simply states "VNC server closed connection".

As I said, I am now away from home for 3 weeks and wonder if there is anything I can try remotely in order to attempt a fix of this problem.  I wonder if there is something to be configured in the router to aid this connection?  Any thoughts and advice would be welcome.  Thank you.

UPDATE: At my most recent attempt at connecting, I was able to easily connect to one of two PCs at home, but still not to the one that prompted me to post my original question here.  I have reconnected to the network via openVPN and was able to successfully ping the problem PC.

Comment: If you can connect to the network then it's worth pinging the computer where VNC should be running to see if it's online at all

Comment: try looking and changing settings in remmina